# Editing an empty value of a UserProperties field

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote code to add an Index number to every task in the task folder.

I created a custom field called "index".

The code loops through all of the tasks and puts the number of the task (not sure what the order is) in the "index" field of each task.

It only works if there is some value assigned to the "index" field. If it is empty, it does nothing.

```
For i = 1 To objFolder.Items.Count
    Set xitem = objFolder.Items(i)
    xitem.UserProperties.Find("index") = i 
    xitem.Save     
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you code assumes the user property is already there - `UserProperties.Find` will return null if the property is not present. You need to use `UserProperties.Add`. It the property is already there, it will return the existing property.

```
For i = 1 To objFolder.Items.Count
  Set xitem = objFolder.Items(i)
  set prop = xitem.UserProperties.Add("index", olNumber) 
  prop.Value = i 
  xitem.Save     
Next i
```